# PHP MSSQL using Apache on Windows and Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, window, installation

How to setup PHP (5.3/5.4) with MSSQL support on a windows development environment, if applications should be deployed to a linux system? So basically, which driver should be used and how (like using `mssql_` functions or PDO or sth.)?

Currently the target system is running PHP 5.1.6 on some CentOS, but this could be updated if needed. We are using the `mssql_` functions for database access. I tried to setup the development machine using [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), but had to find out, that the support for MSSQL driver has been dropped in PHP 5.3.

The suggestion seems to be to use `sqlsrv` driver and functions, but this won't work on the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ODBC, the SQLSrv extension is only intended for use on Windows.